# AWS Network Load Balancer and HTTPS endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elb

I'm learning about network load balancers in AWS and I'm stuck trying to use secure layer connections.

I created

1. the Load balancer of type network.
2. one target group for my application (port 3000 / TCP)
3. one listener for port 443 with protocol TLS and as default action I'm forwarding to the previous target group. I added also the certificate of my domain.
4. an alias to the Load Balancer in route53

What I'd expect is, if I type https://www.this-is-an-example.com:443/home it should proxy to my application (running in port 3000) but keeping a secure connection or using https. But it doesn't work.

When I do `curl https://www.this-is-an-example.com:443/home` I receive the following response: `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

If I try using Postman `Error: socket hang up`

I understand that network load balancers don't care about https, however, how can I use https with my domain and be able to hit the listener and utilize https from client to Load balancer.

Comment: can you explain what is the error you are getting and if you have any security groups defined on the target instances of your target group?

Comment: "But it doesn't work." - is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any errors, screenshots?

Comment: @Marcin You are right! My bad. I added the errors to the original message. Thanks.

Comment: @RezaNasiri The service has a SG that includes a rule for 443. Is that what you were asking? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is your security group. You cannot associate a security group to network load balancer and since they operate at layer 4, you have to make sure your target instances have proper security group that allows access from NLB/Client to the target. this depends if you are using instance target type or IP target type. in instance target type, the source will be actual client and port should be target port(3000) and not 443. in case of IP target type, the source will be NLB's IP and target port is again your target port. you can get more detailed information [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/target-group-register-targets.html#target-security-groups)